# What is a UI thread in windows phone 8?

Tags: multithreading, windows-phone-8, c#-5.0

Hello i am new to developing application. now i am working on an app that have to track the location so it must work in the background when i do so it works will but when i get back to the app the UI is not updated

```
 if (!App.RunningInBackground)
            {
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    one.Text = args.Position.Coordinate.Latitude.ToString();
                    two.Text = args.Position.Coordinate.Longitude.ToString();
                });
            }
```

and on the output

```
The thread 0x7b4 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
```

i do not know what is  UI thread and i checked Google.

Comment: "I checked Google" for what? Because searching for "UI thread" gives me thousands of relevant results.

Comment: Are you seeing a crash/exception? Threads will be created and destroyed somewhat frequently. If you're debugging in Visual Studio, it should break on an exception if there was one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have an app that runs in background, you should use background agents.
For a good [quick start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202941%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) this link is best.

Best practices and advices are found [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

And you want to run your app in background and want to update the textbox in foreground? what do you mean?

UI thread means the main thread in phone foreground app where all the activities take place. Any new async task has to be spawned from this UI thread only.

You have a code because your app has successfully exited the foreground.